# MS SQL - Joining NULL values

Tags: sql-server

I am having a hard time figuring this out in MS SQL. Hope you can guide me with this.

Let me tell you my story:

I have a daily attendance report for merchandisers. Within a day, the merchandisers are moving from one store to another.

So they have an application where they would time in, in the morning, check in when they came to a store, check out to that store, and then time out in the evening.

Okay, now I have a portal where I would gather all the sent data from the application.

Currently, I can retrieve the data, it is fine. My current report looks like this:

```
diser | store  |  date       |time in | time out | check in| check out
------------------------------------------------------------------------
John  | Store 1| 02/06/2018  | 7:00AM | 5:00PM   | 8:00AM  | 9:00AM
------------------------------------------------------------------------
John  | Store 2| 02/06/2018  | 7:00AM | 5:00PM   | 10:00AM | 11:00AM
------------------------------------------------------------------------
John  | Store 3| 02/06/2018  | 7:00AM | 5:00PM   | 1:00PM  | 2:00PM
```

*I will post the screenshot of my table in the portal.*

But my boss wants to see the attendance for today early in the morning. For example, if the merchandiser only has a time in for today, he wants to see that already. My current report will not show if the merchandiser didn't complete his/her attendance for today.

Here is what I have tried:

```
select  ca.SGrp as salesGroupCode,
    ca.SOffc as salesOfficeCode,
    ca.SDst as salesDistrictCode,
    ca.CustCode as customerCode,
    ca.CustNm as customer,
    e.Comp as agency,
    e.LName + ', ' + e.FName as diser,
    CONVERT(date, a.DtFrom) as date,
    convert(varchar,cast(a.DtFrom as time(0)), 109) as timeIn,
    convert(varchar,cast(b.DtFrom  as time(0)), 109) as timeOut,
    convert(varchar,cast(c.DtFrom  as time(0)), 109) as checkIn,
    convert(varchar,cast(d.DtFrom  as time(0)), 109) as checkOut,
    overall_count = COUNT(*) OVER()

from    BigESentData.dbo.tbl_sentAttendance as a

    left join BigESentData.dbo.tbl_sentAttendance b
    on  b.CellNum = a.CellNum and
        convert(varchar, a.DtFrom, 111) = convert(varchar, b.DtFrom, 111) and
        b.TransTyp = 6

    left join BigESentData.dbo.tbl_sentAttendance c
    on  b.CellNum = a.CellNum and
        c.DtFrom between a.DtFrom and isnull(b.DtFrom, @dateFrom) and
        c.TransTyp = 7
    left join BigEMasterData.dbo.tbl_Customers as ca
    on c.CustCode = ca.CustCode


    left join BigESentData.dbo.tbl_sentAttendance d
    on  b.CellNum = a.CellNum and
        d.DtFrom between a.DtFrom and isnull(b.DtFrom, @dateFrom) and
        c.CustCode = d.CustCode and
        d.TransTyp = 8

    left join BigESentData.dbo.tbl_sentRegistration e
    on a.CellNum = e.CellNum

    inner join BigEUsers.dbo.user_role_area as f
    on ca.SDst = f.area_id

    inner join BigEUsers.dbo.users as g
    on f.role_id = g.role_id


where   convert(varchar, a.DtFrom, 111) between @dateFrom and @dateTo
AND    ca.SGrp LIKE ISNULL('%' + @salesGroupCode + '%', ca.SGrp)
AND    ca.SOffc LIKE ISNULL('%' + @salesOfficeCode + '%', ca.SOffc)
AND    ca.SDst LIKE ISNULL('%' + @salesDistrictCode + '%', ca.SDst)
AND    a.TransTyp= 5
AND    g.id = @userId

order by a.DtFrom desc, diser asc, timeIn asc

OFFSET @start ROWS
FETCH NEXT @pageSize ROWS ONLY;
```

Here is the screenshot of my table in the portal:
[image: My portal table]

How can I achieve this? Hope you could help me. I already used left joins. Maybe I am designing it wrong. Any tips and suggestion would be appreciated very much. Thankyou.

Comment: This type of thing is MUCH easier if you can give us the code to create your table and maybe some sample data.

Comment: Hi @KennethFisher, Thanks for your comment. I will add data now, hope you are still there when I post the sample data.  Btw, the table screenshot that I posted, doesn't matter much. It is just the output of the query. I am having a hardtime in the sql query. Thanks Kenneth, I'll get back soon with the sample data.

Comment: You used LEFT join to join `ca` but then `ca` columns apear in `WHERE`, which turns that join to `INNER`. Try moving these 3 (ca) conditions to the `on` clause: `left join BigEMasterData.dbo.tbl_Customers as ca
    on c.CustCode = ca.CustCode and (...)`

Comment: The joins to `f` and `g` should probably be left joins, too. We can't be sure without sample data.

Comment: what is the diff between timein vs checkin ?I will suggest first find only timein and timeout and comment rest,when this is correct then move ahead.